# Статическая константа

Tags: c++

Можно ли объявить с инициализацией `static` переменную типа `double/float` и производных внутри класса?

Если да, то каким способом? Если нет, то почему?

Comment: Закрывашки, руки прочь от вопроса!

Comment: Уважаемые закрывающие, вопрос выглядит вполне прилично. Если вы голосуете против, не сочтите за труд оставить комментарий, объясняющий, что же по вашему мнению в вопросе не так.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Вы можете создавать константные статически члены класса со спецификатором `constexpr` и инициализировать их внутри определения класса.

Например

```
#include <iostream>

struct A
{
    static constexpr double d = 10.15;
};    

constexpr double A::d;

int main()
{
    A a;

    std::cout << a.d << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Ранее этого нельзя было делать, так как тип `double` разными компиляторами представлялся по-разному и более того было расхождение между препроцессорами и компиляторами, как они представляют тип `double`.

Вот, что, например, пишет Страуструп в своем предложении по включению в стандарт спецификатора `constexpr`:

> Traditionally, evaluation of floating-point constant expression at
>   compile-time is a **thorny issue**.

Comment: Определение `constexpr double A::d;` необязательно.

Comment: "Ранее этого нельзя было делать, так как тип double разными компиляторами представлялся по-разному" --
А сейчас? В 3.9.1 Fundamental types ([basic.fundamental]) по-прежнему написано: "The value representation of
floating-point types is implementation-defined".

Comment: @RuslanGaripov А сейчас договорились на счет этого. Константа особо не влияет. А вот, например, использовать как параметр шаблона нельзя.

Comment: @RuslanGaripov Я внес ссылку на Страуструпа в свой ответ.

Comment: @RuslanGaripov определение вне класса требуется, если идет обращение к статическому члену через объект класса, т.е. как в примере `a.d`, или если требуется знать адрес члена, например, `&A::d`. В иных случаях достаточно только записи внутри класса.

Answer (score 6):

Нельзя было до C++11. Такое можно было делать только с "integral types" (integers, chars, bools). Используя constexpr такое можно делать и для других типов.

C++11 standard, 9.4.2 Static data members

> If a **non-volatile const static data member is of integral or enumeration type**, its declaration in the class definition can specify a brace-or-equal-initializer in which every initializer-clause that is an assignment-
>   expression is a constant expression (5.19).
>   **A static data member of literal type can be declared** in the class definition **with the constexpr specifier**; if so, its declaration shall specify a brace-or-equal-initializer in which every initializer-clause that is an assignment-уxpression is a constant expression

Comment: "Если нет, то почему?"

Comment: Будет очень здорово, если вы добавите подробностей. )

Comment: Добавил! :) Про _constexpr_ сам не знал, как оказалось!

Comment: @RuslanGaripov: ну вот, и вы что-то новое узнали в процессе. Добро пожаловать на StackOverflow на русском. ))

Comment: @RuslanGaripov хорошо бы было перевести цитату на русский язык, конечно en почти все знают, но сайт все таки на русском.